# How to add UIKit to an Xcode project?

Tags: xcode, uikit

I've imported another programmer's project into Xcode and get the error "UIKit/UIKit.h file not found."  I tried right clicking the Frameworks folder but didn't see a way to add it. How can I add the UIKit to this project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Navigate to the target and go to `Build Phases` and add UIKit to `Link Binary With Libraries`.

From the Comments to this post:

> MonkeyBusiness: Sorry to waste your time. I had set the project up as MacOS rather than iOS. I'm new to Apple and iOS as you can see.

Comment: Thanks, but UIKit is not in the list of available Frameworks. It should be between TWAIN and vecLib, but isn't.

Comment: My list is in alphabetical order and the last framework is XgridFoundation.framework. I wonder why UIKit doesn't show up?

Comment: Sorry to waste your time.  I had set the project up as MacOS rather than iOS.  I'm new to Apple and iOS as you can see.

Comment: Ok, then make this an answer an check it as correct in case someone encounters the same issue.

Comment: Ahh thank you! I've accidentally added my test target as an OSX target instead of an iOS test target. Snap.

Comment: If the answer isn't "link binary with libraries" and is instead "oops, created the wrong project type", then the info from the comments should be added to the answer so that when the mods do a comment cleanup here we won't lose valuable info. Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 11):

Check that you are using a iOS project and not a Mac OSX one - UIKit is only for the iPhone/iPad