# Handling trackpad events using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa

From the developer docs by apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingTouchEvents/HandlingTouchEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH13-SW10), I came across this.

> Instead of handling a gesture, you could choose to track and handle the “raw” touches that make up the gesture.

Examples in the documentation are given for Objective-C however not for Swift. How can I track and handle these "raw" touches in Swift globally? Not just within an NSView?

My class:

```
import Cocoa
import Security
import AppKit

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    @IBOutlet weak var dropMenu: NSMenu!
    @IBOutlet weak var resetView: NSView!
    @IBOutlet weak var resetWindow: NSPanel!
    @IBOutlet weak var keyLabel: NSTextField!

    let statusItem = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().statusItemWithLength(-1);

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        NSApp.setActivationPolicy(NSApplicationActivationPolicy.Accessory)
        let menuIcon = NSImage(named: "menuIcon")
        menuIcon?.template = true;
        statusItem.image = menuIcon;
        statusItem.menu = dropMenu;
    }

    @IBAction func quit(sender: NSMenuItem) {
        NSApplication.sharedApplication().terminate(self)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch: AnyObject! in touches {
            let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
            //Use touchLocation for example: button.containsPoint(touchLocation) meaning the user has pressed the button.
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated Again, NSEvent:**

(touchesBegan UIEvent etc is for iOS, MacOS is different and uses NSEvent)

NSEvent is what you want to look into, where you can use mouseDown, mouseUp, mouseMove etc and then get the cursor point:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/mouseDown:

Swift Example of mouseDown:

```
override func mouseDown(event: NSEvent) {
    let point: NSPoint = event.locationInView
    print("X: \'point.x'")
    print("Y: \'point.y'")
}
```

Objc Example:

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event {
    NSLog( @"mouse down event: %@", event );
    NSPoint point = [event locationInWindow];
    NSLog( @"mouseDown location: (%d,%d)", point.x, point.y );
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey i'm unable to import UIEvent, any clues? I looked in the frameworks list and UIKit isn't there.

Comment: You on Swift 1 or 2?

Comment: @user3813948 Any luck with this, did you get it to work?

Comment: i get the warning in red "Use of undeclared type 'UITouch'" and "Use of undeclared type 'UIEvent'".

Comment: Import UIKIt at top of your file

Comment: Put you whole code in your question and we can have a look

Comment: Okay, but UIKit is not found in my frameworks folder.

Comment: Add UIKit to linked frameworks then and also make sure you've set up an iOS project/target and not a MacOS one (as that is different and doesn't use UIKit which might be your issue) See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055937/how-to-add-uikit-to-an-xcode-project

Comment: but this app is for Mac does that make a difference?

Comment: Yeah Mac apps are different, MacOS is not iOS and are based off different frameworks

Comment: @user3813948 Just updated again with NSEvent and mouseDown method to get mouse click etc